# How can i use str split in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

[in erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfRBO.png)

i can not use str split in ruby.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbz6G.png)

help me!

Comment: Please [ask better](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Just see on 2nd line ([your link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbz6G.png)) messages that says **Undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass** that's means you are calling `split` on nil class not on `string`. Just run `'hello world'.split(' ')` on your `irb` and you will get `["hello", "world"]`.